# Как определить, что была нажата клавиша Enter в консоли?

Tags: c

Я хочу отловить, нажата ли клавиша Enter в консоли.

Если клавиша была нажата, выполнить какие-то действия.

Как отловить нажатие клавиши на языке C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы считываете данные из входного потока, то определить можно по соответствующему коду.

```
printf("%d",getchar()); //Примерно вот так выведет на печать код символа. У Enter он равен 13
```

Если же Вы имеете ввиду в целом нажатие клавиши Enter в консоли применительно не к программе, а к окну консоли, то, как минимум, необходимо знать о какой операционной системе идет речь.

Comment: А я почему-то  всегда считал, что <Enter> (т.е. **последний символ**, который читается из stdin при нажатии на эту клавишу) это `\n` с кодом 10 (десятичное) (а не `\r`, код 13 (ага, в винде если нажать <Enter> и файл открыт как *text*, получаем пару `\r\n` (и первый из них Вы написали в ответе)))